# How to run a windows scheduled task 20 mins after system startup?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

In windows scheduled tasks properties, you can only choose "at system startup" without being able to assign a specific delay such as 20 minutes, so I wonder how can I setup a schedule task if I want it to run after the system "fully" starts up(you know how fast this can be in XP)? Hope you guys know the answer. Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but I will note that the Windows 7 task scheduler is much improved and has this option.

Comment: Not sure in Windows XP. In recent Windows (like Windows Server 2008) you can specify "Delay task" in Trigger options of Scheduled Task

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a scheduled task to run an app you've written, have the app you've written sleep for 20 minutes and then run the original app.

Comment: That's horrible... but it makes the job :).